# Why does the function ID3D11DeviceContext::Map sometimes produce a mapped subresource with a different resolution to my texture?

Tags: c++, graphics, directx, directx-11

When using the `Map` function on an existing render texture, in certain situations, the output `RowPitch` and `DepthPitch` are altered, producing a subtly different resolutions.

For example, if the source texture (BGRA 8bit) has the resolution `1559x1080` with a bit depth of `4`, the resulting `D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE` has the resolution `1568x1080` (calculated by dividing the output `RowPitch` ( 6272 ) by `BitDepth` (4) ).

However, if the source texture has the resolution `1568x1080`, then the mapped sub-resource will have a `RowPitch` of 6272 as expected.

While I can think of many reasons for this being altered (ie optimising for MipMap levels, fitting existing memory constraints), I would like to understand why and what the exact algorithm is for calculating the output `RowPitch` so that we can enforce rules for the source texture.

Comment: It could be different on different graphics cards.

Comment: @user253751 thanks. Is this common? It's almost the only instance when I've seen resolution constraints like this in d3d...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your answer, I'm guessing you're running this on a somewhat modern x86-64 CPU.

From some basic math on the values you gave, the algorithm appears to be the following for your PC:

```
RowPitch = AlignUp((BytesPerTexel * TextureWidth), 64);
```

Here, `AlignUp` rounds the first argument to the smallest value larger than or equal to the first argument cleanly divisible by the second argument.

The value 64 is not arbitrary - it is either the size of a cache line on your CPU, or the maximum size of a single PCI transfer from the CPU to your GPU. Since the pointer returned by `Map` lives on the CPU, my guess is it's a match to the cache line size, in which case it could be different based on the exact CPU you're running on.

As for the exact implementation details, you'd have to get a Microsoft engineer to chime in. Overall, however, this would seem to be the most likely explanation.

In terms of solving the problem of texture sizes, the best option would actually be to just ignore it for the most part. D3D and the GPU will ignore data that falls outside the texture width, but within the row pitch. Just use the texture width as the write boundary, and the row pitch as an element size.

It's worth noting that this happens automatically all the time - if you have a C array of structures, each of which has a size that's not divisible by their alignment, the compiler will insert padding between the structures to keep them all aligned. The same thing is happening here, but the compiler can't hide it from you.

Comment: Thank you so much for that really detailed explanation. I've taken your advice and have just extracted the valuable parts of our texture from the padded output. My misunderstanding about this in the beginning was thinking that the texture had been resized when it had in fact just been padded.

Answer (score 0):

RowPitch and DepthPitch can indeed be aligned by a certain size (for various reasons).

This is not changing the resolution of your texture, it's only some padding data added at the end of each row.

There is no algorithm to determine the value of row pitch, since it can change depending on the GPU manufacturer/model/driver.

So the only way to determine it is to query by the map function and if rowpitch == pixelsize*width (or your custom pitch, some image APIs also apply padding in CPU), you can do a full memcpy, if not you have to copy row per row.

On a side note I had a check on my machine and both Intel and Nvidia card report an alignment of 128, but as said that can change, so you should not rely on values you are getting and expect they will be the same in another machine.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice. It is exactly what we ended up doing. I've given the answer to @Alex below because he went a bit further into the underlying algorithm and how the gpu / cpu architecture works, but your answer was also very useful